# Selenium Dynamic Dojo Table iterating

Tags: javascript, selenium, exception, dojo, automated-tests

I have a Dynamic grid table made with dojo kit in the front end. It has a main div element inside which contains 3 more div elements. The 3 divs are dynamic elements and loads only when u scroll down within the grid.

Each of the 3 elements contain 25 elements at max.

Please advice me a way to first dynamically get all the div elements inside the main element and iterate the table for a particular column.

Below is the code I am trying to get focus inside the table grid and scroll.

```
WebElement tableClickFirstElement = table.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dojox_grid__View_1']/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[6]"));
    tableClickFirstElement.click();
    bd.pause(3000);


    for(int j=0; j<100;j++){
        table.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
        bd.pause(300);
    }
    bd.pause(3000);

    for(int j=0; j<125;j++){
        table.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP);
        bd.pause(300);
    }
    bd.pause(3000);
```

Below is the code(continuation of above) I am trying to fetch value from column of the table i want to

```
    if(table.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dojox_grid__View_1']/div/div/div[1]")).isDisplayed()){

        for(int a=1;a<=25;a++){ 
        WebElement tableTwoColumn3 = table.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dojox_grid__View_1']/div/div/div[1]/div["+a+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]"));   
        tableTwoColumn3.click();
        bd.pause(2000);
        String abc = tableTwoColumn3.getText();

        WebElement tableTwoColumn6 = table.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dojox_grid__View_1']/div/div/div[1]/div["+a+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[6]"));
        tableTwoColumn6.click();
        bd.pause(2000);
        String cde = tableTwoColumn6.getText();
```

}
}

After getting the values I compare it with excel and press a different button outside the grid and then get focus back by clicking into the next row in the grid by as shown above.

I am able to run the for loop for only 1 iteration and the second iteration fails with staleElemenentReferenceException at String abc = tableTwoColumn3.getText();

I am new to selenium so I am not sure where I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Could you attach html structure of your page (at least some part of it)? Does  `[@id='dojox_grid__View_1']/div/div/div[1]` contain 25 child divs, each of them containing a table, or your table contains 25 rows?

Comment: This div [@id='dojox_grid__View_1']/div/div/div[1]] contains 25 more divs and each of the 25 divs contains a table like this [@id='dojox_grid__View_1']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]